# Removing checkbox highlighting on mousedown

Tags: html, css

After pressing down with mouse on the label, the checkbox is getting highlighted. I want to remove this effect. So far I tried `preventDefault()` on the even of `onMouseDown` event, but it does not affect the highlighting.

[image: First checkbox is highlighted after pressing down with mouse on label]

(Upper checkbox is highlighted/darker - effect on mousedown event on label)

Besides the lack of highlighting the on/off behavior of checkbox after clicking on label should stay unaffected.

Extra info: I cannot achieve it with modifying the styles of checkbox, because as next step I want to use the no-highlighting behaviour only for part of the label (links inside the label particulary).

JSFiddle showcasing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/o59udsLk/1/

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML and CSS.  Also, which browser(s) are you seeing this in?

Comment: There is no css. I am checking it in Chrome (55). I updated the description with JSFiddle showcasing the issue.

Comment: Not sure that i understand - i don't see any 'highlight', just checkbox is checked, when clicking on label - do you want this?  http://jsfiddle.net/o59udsLk/2/  (setting of pointer-events to none in css will remove default behavior).

Comment: @nevermind Please compare the two checkboxes in the screenshot in question. The top one has the highlight which is visible during "mousedown" event on label.

Comment: i can not see the state from your picture either in jsfiddle, or produce it locally. you are describing. Please show us the code for the picture. When exactly get the checkbox highlighted? on MouseDown (and hold) or before/after that?

Comment: i correct myself. it's reproducible. i can see it now.

Comment: Did u check myanswer. @Michał

Answer (score 6):

You cannot control the effect of checkbox on `mousedown` on a label because this is a OS generated effect. For this you need to change the appearance of your checkbox using CSS styles & fonts (maybe).

Custom CSS Checkboxes:

```css
body {
 background: #e6e6e6;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.control-group {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 210px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 30px;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.control {
 font-size: 18px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.control input {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 left: 0;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #e6e6e6;
}

/* Hover and focus states */
.control input:focus ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #ccc;
}

/* Checked state */
.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:hover {
 background: #2aa1c0;
}

/* Disabled state */
.control input:disabled ~ .control__indicator {
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: .6;
 background: #e6e6e6;
}

/* Check mark */
.control__indicator:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 content: '';
}

/* Show check mark */
.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:after {
 display: block;
}

/* Checkbox tick */
.control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
 top: 4px;
 left: 8px;
 width: 3px;
 height: 8px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 border: solid #fff;
 border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

/* Disabled tick colour */
.control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
 border-color: #7b7b7b;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
 <h1>Checkboxes</h1>
 <label class="control control--checkbox">First checkbox
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--checkbox">Second checkbox
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--checkbox">Disabled
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--checkbox">Disabled & checked
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to use `outline: none`?

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  outline: none;
}
```

Something like below -

```js
$('label[for="startClientFromWebEnabled"]').mousedown(function(e) { 
        console.log('mouse down!!')
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">
    Client Launch From Web:
  </label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" 
         id="startClientFromWebEnabled"     name="startClientFromWebEnabled" 
         data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable"/>
</td>
```

Updated jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/o59udsLk/6/

Hope this will help you in some way (y).

Comment: The highlight is still there, nothing changed (chrome 55).

Comment: @Michał Not sure if it is applicable, i am testing it in mac sierra - chrome 55.0.2883.87 and using keydown seems issue is fixed while reproducible on jsfiddle provide by you. Which os you are using?

Comment: Mac Sierra, chrome 55. The issue is in highlight, not the blue outline. Please look on the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dummy checkbox and check that dummy checkbox when the original gets checked

```js
$('#startClientFromWebEnabled').click(function(e) {
  $('#dummy').prop('checked', $('#startClientFromWebEnabled').is(":checked"));
});
```

```css
body{
  zoom:300%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">Client Launch From Web:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dummy" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWebEnabled" name="startClientFromWebEnabled" data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable" style="display:none;" />
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Update:

To disable click on the checkbox use a overlay using a span

```js
$('#startClientFromWebEnabled').click(function(e) {
  $('#dummy').prop('checked', $('#startClientFromWebEnabled').is(":checked"));
});
$('td:nth-child(2) > span').click(function(e) {
  $('#startClientFromWebEnabled').click();
});
$('td:nth-child(2) > span').css('width',$('td:nth-child(2)').outerWidth()).css('height',$('td:nth-child(2)').outerHeight());
```

```css
body{
  zoom:300%;
  }
td:nth-child(2) > span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 64px;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">Client Launch From Web:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span></span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dummy" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWebEnabled" name="startClientFromWebEnabled" data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable" style="display:none;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      hai
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### SOLUTION WITH OVERLAY

(without any dummy checkbox)

Use 2 overlays(one for label td, another one for checkbox td) using css `:before` and calculate their width & height in jquery

```js
$('td').click(function(e) {
  toggleCheckbox();
});
$('<style>td:nth-child(2):before{width:' + $('td:nth-child(2)').outerWidth() + 'px;height:' + $('td:nth-child(2)').outerHeight() + 'px}</style>').appendTo('head');
$('<style>td:nth-child(1):before{width:' + $('td:nth-child(1)').outerWidth() + 'px;height:' + $('td:nth-child(1)').outerHeight() + 'px}</style>').appendTo('head');

function toggleCheckbox(){
  chkBox=$('#startClientFromWebEnabled'); 
  chkBox.prop("checked",!chkBox.prop("checked"));
}
```

```css
body{
  zoom:300%;
  }
td:before{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 64px;
  content:' ';
  z-index:10;
  width:attr(data-width);
  height:attr(data-height);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">Client Launch From Web:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWebEnabled" name="startClientFromWebEnabled" data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Another Simple solution:

Use `pointer-events: none;` on the label and checkbox and handle the click event though its `td`

```js
$('td:has(input:checkbox, label[for!=""])').addClass('test');
$('td.test').click(function(e) {
  toggleCheckbox(this);
});
function toggleCheckbox(tis){
  var chkBox;
  if($(tis).find("input:checkbox").length>0)
    chkBox=$(tis).find("input:checkbox").first();
  else if($(tis).find('label[for!=""]').length>0)
    chkBox=$('#'+$(tis).find('label[for!=""]').first().prop('for')); 
  chkBox.prop("checked",!chkBox.prop("checked"));
}
```

```css
body{
  zoom:300%;
  }

td.test > label,td.test > input {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">Client Launch From Web:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWebEnabled" name="startClientFromWebEnabled" data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove `for=""` from the label and from your script, please refer to the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/o59udsLk/3/

Comment: This also removes the ability to toggle the checkbox, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that it is possible to prevent the highlighting in all browsers/systems.
The preventDefault() works as you want in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

But whats the point?! 
Click and hold a few seconds. Only then the style changes are perceived.
It's not about style. Isn't it?

You wrote:

> Extra info: I cannot achieve it with modifying the styles of checkbox,
>   because as next step
>   **I want to use the no-highlighting behaviour only
>   for ... links inside the label ...**

**Solution 1:**

So you could achieve your goal, by splitting the label in parts:

- A label before the link
- Link
- A label after the link

On clicking on the link, nothing happens with the checkbox, if you don't want to. If you want, you can attach events.

Like in this code: (http://jsfiddle.net/o59udsLk/5/)

```js
$('label[for="startClientFromWebEnabled"]').mousedown(function(e) { 
        console.log('mouse down!!')
        // remove highlighting in Firefox but not in Chrome
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });

$('a').click(function(e) { 
        console.log('link clicked!!')
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">(with preventDefault) before </label>
       <a href="#">link</a>
       <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled"> after</label>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWebEnabled" 
                  name="startClientFromWebEnabled" 
                  data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable"  />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <label for="compareWithMe">(without preventDefault) before </label>
       <a href="#">link</a>
       <label for="compareWithMe"> after</label>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="checkbox" id="compareWithMe" name="compareWithMe"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

**Solution 2:**

Other solution could be to replace the default checkboxes with custom ones. The you will have more control over the appearance.

For example:

```css
.customCheckbox input[type="checkbox"] {
     display: none;
    }
    
    .customCheckbox span {
     width: 11px;
     height: 11px;
     margin: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background: white;
    }
    
    .customCheckbox :checked+span {
     background: green;
    }
```

```html
<label class="customCheckbox">
     (custom Checkbox) before 
     <a href="#" onclick="console.log('link clicked')">link</a>
     after
     <input type="checkbox" id="inputInsideLabel" name="inputInsideLabel"/>
     <span></span>
    </label>
```

There are many others customized checkboxes and other form elements.
Other example with "font awesome": https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk
Or here: [example with bootstrap and font awesome](http://www.cssscript.com/pretty-checkbox-radio-inputs-bootstrap-awesome-bootstrap-checkbox-css/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the label to a span, and remove the for="startClientFromWebEnabled"

You said "next step I want to use the no-highlighting behaviour only for part of the label (links inside the label particulary)."

You can then edit parts of the span to put them inside labels and use the for="startClientFromWebEnabled" for the parts that are clickable.

```
<td>
    <span><label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">[click]</label> Client Launch <label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">[click]</label> From Web:</span>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWebEnabled" name="startClientFromWebEnabled" data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable" />
</td>
```